«И то» — союз? Или союз + указательное слово?
Я собираюсь почитать, и то если не лень.
Во-первых, не уверена в постановке запятых, а во-вторых, не понимаю, чем является «и то» в этом предложении. И «если не лень» является придаточным условия?

"И то" не союз + указательное слово, а самостоятельный союз.

«Я собираюсь почитать, и то если не лень».


а если еще брать в пример «только».  я буду готова(,) только(,)если встану вовремя. здесь «только» чем будет являться?

Корректно с запятой перед частицей только, сопровождающей подчинительный союз если: Отменить формирование отчета можно, только если он находится в статусах «Создано», «Проверяется», «Формирование».  - См.: https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8&mode=all "Я буду готова, только если встану вовремя".

возник еще вопрос, «и то если» будет восприниматься как бы как один союз? есть еще тема про стык двух союзов,но там насколько я помню немножко все по другому
